# Time difference in R: POSIXct error

Tags: r, time, posixct

I am using this code to calculate time difference.

```
ctym <- lapply(G, function(x) x[k,2])
y <- lapply(G, function(x) x[j,2])
t1 <- c(y,ctym)
dt1 <- as.POSIXct(t1)
dtyme <- difftime(dt1[2],dt1[1],units = "mins")
```

Output for t1 is:

```
 [[1]]
      time_occurred 
"2013-04-01 20:27:18"

[[2]]
    time_occurred 
"2013-04-01 20:27:48"
```

Error I am getting is:
Error in as.POSIXct.default(t1) : 
  do not know how to convert 't1' to class “POSIXct”

What's wrong here?

Comment: Like @LostBrit said, you need to share a data sample. Please see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `lapply` returns a list. Using `c` on two list returns a list. There is no `as.POSIXct` method for lists.

Answer (score 4):

t1 is not a POSIXct object. I think it might be a list at the moment. You'll need to do something like...

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct(unlist(t1), format = "%y-%m-%d H:M:S"))
```

.... to get `t1` into the right format to do some maths.

This might not be required if you use `paste()` instead of `c()` to combine your data, but without your data we can't really tell.

If you could post some of your data we can see what we can do :)

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is also showing the same error. My G is:
`[[1]]
     event_id   time_occurred        
[1,] "MX050113" "2013-04-01 20:27:48"
[2,] "MX050113" "2013-04-01 20:27:18"`

Comment: @anu, this doesn't help me. You need to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example